# Псевдо класс :hover работает на половине блока span

Tags: html, css, css3, filter

Почему-то псевдо класс :hover работает на половине span. Дожен блюрить весь родительский блок не считая текста.
Рализовал с помощю фильтра наложеного на span

```css
site-slider-block-a1 {
  position: relative;
}

span {
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/ff00ff/000000');
}

span:hover {
  filter: blur(5px)
}
```

```html
<div class="site-slider-block-a1">
  <span></span>
  <h1>Сайт-визитка</h1>
  <p></p>
  <button></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Здравствуйте. `Дожен блюрить весь родительский блок не считая текста` Я попробовал запустить ваш код, он и так размывает весь родительский блок, что ещё требуется? Напишите пожалуйста подробнее.

Comment: Что значит `Дожен блюрить весь родительский блок не считая текста.`?